# ClassNotFoundException for SpringBoot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am new to SpringBoot.

I created an API and I can successfully run it into IDE (Intellij)

Problem is when I try to run the packaged JAR or WAR. I get exception: ClassNotFoundException

I am using Spring 3.2.0, Kotlin and Gradle DSL

In build.gradle.kts I have the following:

```
plugins {
war
id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.10"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.10"
kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.10"
}


springBoot {
mainClass = "com.example.api.ExampleApplication"
}
```

and

```
tasks.withType<War> {
manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.api.ExampleApplication"
}
```

The build produces the needed Manifest files which correctly contain the class name.

But still, I get the error.

I tried to modify the main class name in build.gradle.kts with all possible names but I have not managed to make it work.

Comment: Remove the `springBoot` and `tasks.withType` and just run `gradle build` to get the correct jar or war file. Don't export it from intellij or try to be smart and create your own jar or war task.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share structure of the project ? Is it a multi-module spring boot application? If yes then go the module where do you have ExampleApplication and try to add following code in build.gradle.kts file.

```
springBoot {
   mainClass.set("com.example.api.ExampleApplication")
}
```

If it's not a multi module project then simply add above code in parent build.gradle.kts file. Please give a try and let me know if that works or not.